# Replace string with comma or without with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string with this value format:

```
$str = "Apple, Orange, Computer-Hardware, preg_replace, 50k";
```

or

```
$str = "Computer";
```

How can I convert it with preg_replace to:

```
$str = "<a href='p.php?s=Apple'>Apple</a>, <a href='p.php?s=Orange'>Orange</a>, 
<a href='p.php?s=Computer-Hardware'>Computer-Hardware</a>, <a href='p.php?s=preg_replace'>preg_replace</a>,  <a href='p.php?s=50k'>50k</a>";

$str = "<a href='p.php?s=Computer'>Computer</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/([\w-]+)/', '<a href=\'p.php?s=$1\'>$1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: In the string between some words can be these two characters - , _ or numbers: ex.: preg-replcae , 56k, 50000.

Comment: @TimCoorper: in the result comma is also with the words: "<a href='p.php?s=Apple,'>Apple,</a>"

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
$str = "Apple, Orange, Computer-Hardware, preg_replace, 50k";
$str = preg_replace('/([^,\s]+)/', "<a href='p.php?s=$1'>$1</a>", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<a href='p.php?s=Apple'>Apple</a>, <a href='p.php?s=Orange'>Orange</a>, <a href='p.php?s=Computer-Hardware'>Computer-Hardware</a>, <a href='p.php?s=preg_replace'>preg_replace</a>, <a href='p.php?s=50k'>50k</a>
```